# Redirecting from wp-content?

Tags: redirect

For some reason, Google has picked up a PDF version of one of our articles from wp-content and ranked it for one of our higher-value keywords. I'm looking to redirect that PDF link to a link for the original article, but I can't seem to get the Redirect plugin working for the wp-content URL.

If you have any ideas for how I could redirect from the wp-content PDF url to the original article URL, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: That's because the request is served directly from disk if it exists as a file, and only given to WordPress to process if the path doesn't match a file or directory. The usual Apache config for this is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your .htaccess file, try the following

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(Your_Artile_Name)\.pdf your_article.php [L,R=301]`

Substituting your actual file names for 'Your_article_name' and 'your_article'.

If you have a Microsoft server, [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/23/converting-apache-htaccess-rules-to-iis-web-config-using-iis-manager-for-azure-websites/) explains how to convert .htaccess to web.config